# Const Double Indexing with [][] in Matrix Class

Tags: c++, c++11, matrix, operator-overloading

The following code contains a simple example of a Matrix class, with double indexing [][] enabled using a 'proxy' Row class.

```
#include <valarray>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class Matrix {

private:

  // Data members
  int nRows_;
  int nColumns_;
  std::valarray<T> data_;

public:

  // Constructor
  Matrix(const int nRows,
         const int nColumns)
    : nRows_{nRows},
      nColumns_{nColumns},
      data_{std::valarray<T>(nRows*nColumns)} {}

  // Row friend class to enable double indexing
  class Row {   
    friend class Matrix;

  private:

    // Constructor
    Row(Matrix& parent,
        int row)
      : parent_{parent},
        row_{row} {}

    // Data members
    Matrix& parent_;
    int row_;

  public:

    // Index columns
    T& operator[](int column) {
      int nColumns{parent_.nColumns_};
      int element{row_*nColumns + column};
      return parent_.data_[element];
    }
  };

  // Index rows
  Row operator[](int row) {
    return Row(*this, row);
  }
};
```

However, this doesn't allow double indexing of a const Matrix. For example, the below code fails to compile when the last line is included.

```
int main() {

  Matrix<int> a{3,3};
  const Matrix<int> b{3,3};
  std::cout << a[1][2];
  std::cout << b[1][2];
}
```

So the question is, how can I modify my Matrix class to allow for double indexing of const Matrix objects?

Answer (score 1):

Since `b` is a `const` Matrix, you need to add `const` versions of your indexing operator.

```
Row operator[](int row) const { ... }
```

This will require additional changes to the `Row` class (or a second proxy class) to handle the `const Matrix &` and `const` overload of `operator[]`.

Comment: So I have tried making the changes `Row operator[](int row) const { ... }` and `const T& operator[](int column) const { ... }` but it still doesn't compile. I don't really understand why that doesn't work, hence I think I'm lacking a logical understanding of why things need/need not be const...

Comment: And also `const Matrix& parent_;`. So that's four extra consts in total. I'm also ignoring the non-const version for now.

Comment: @Watw you do not really need a non-const version unless your operation are meant to change fields of your class

Answer (score 0):

> I think I'm lacking a logical understanding of why things need/need not be const

It depends if you can modify argument or not. in general `operator[]` should not change object (unless it does, but then...ugh), it should return reference to object's resource. Tada! Your implementation doesn't allow that, because `valarray` is `const` then. You cant assign const matrix reference to

```
 Matrix& parent_;
```

And as result

```
 Row(const Matrix& parent, int row)
```

Why store `Matrix` itself... I'd stored reference of `valarray`.

Actually I would ditch container and create own transparent array in heap. that way Row would have a reference to part of array and length of row, nearly zero of overhead.