# Class operators

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

I'm having a problem to make the code:

```
void main(){
     Matrix c(rows,cols);//rows & cols are int numbers
     c[0][0]=2//the line that I'm having a problem to do the operator
}

//My class defined like this: 
class Matrix{
public:
     Matrix(int rows,int cols): rows(rows), cols(cols){
         mat= new double*[cols];
         for( int i=0; i<rows;i++){
             *mat=new double[i];
         }
     }
private:
     int rows,cols;
     double **mat;
};
```

How can I make an operator that will help me to do the line that I'm having a problem with?

Comment: You should note that `void main` is not valid C++. Only `int main`, so it's better to use that because a) it's what the C++ rules dictate and b) it's shorter to write anyway

Comment: @MooingDuck It's in the constructor body. The phrase "method" has no particular meaning in C++ but I think in the colloquial sense we can consider special member functions such as constructors to be "methods".

Comment: You could make a `double& Matrix::operator()(int r, int c);` way of accessing elements in the matrix.

Answer (score 2):

There are no `operator [][]`, but `operator[]`. So that one should return something for which you can use `[]` too (pointer or proxy class).

In your case, you might simply do:

```
double* operator[](int i) { return mat[i]; }
const double* operator[](int i) const { return mat[i]; }
```

For more complicated cases, you have to return a proxy class.

Answer (score 1):

Don't dynamically allocate in two dimensions like that. It's [poison for your cache, and completely pointless](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38244670/560648). I see it [all the time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49015885/560648) and I wish I didn't! Make yourself a nice `std::vector<double>` of size `rows*cols` instead.

Anyway, the trick to permit `[width][height]` is a *proxy class*. Have your `operator[]` return an instance of a class that has its own `operator[]` to do the second-level lookup.

Something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Matrix
{
    Matrix(const size_t columns, const size_t rows)
       : columns(columns)
       , rows(rows)
       , data(columns*rows, 0)
    {}

    size_t index(const size_t x, const size_t y) const
    {
        return x + y*columns;
    }

    double& at(const size_t x, const size_t y)
    {
        return data[index(x, y)];
    }

    double at(const size_t x, const size_t y) const
    {
        return data[index(x, y)];
    }

    template <bool Const>
    struct LookupHelper
    {
        using ParentType = std::conditional_t<Const, const Matrix, Matrix>;
        using ReturnType = std::conditional_t<Const, double, double&>;

        LookupHelper(ParentType& parent, const size_t x) : parent(parent), x(x) {}

        ReturnType operator[](const size_t y)
        {
            return parent.data[parent.index(x, y)];
        }

        const ReturnType operator[](const size_t y) const
        {
            return parent.data[parent.index(x, y)];
        }

    private:
        ParentType& parent;
        const size_t x;
    };

    LookupHelper<false> operator[](const size_t x)
    {
        return {*this, x};
    }

    LookupHelper<true> operator[](const size_t x) const
    {
        return {*this, x};
    }

private:
    const size_t columns, rows;
    std::vector<double> data;
};

int main()
{
    Matrix m(42, 3);
    m[15][3] = 1;
    std::cout << m[15][3] << '\n';
}
```

*(In reality, you'd want to make it moveable and it could doubtlessly be tidied up a bit.)*

Certainly, [switching to `operator()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28087605/560648) or [a `.at(width, height)` member function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30464186/560648) is a lot easier…

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49822848/const-double-indexing-with-in-matrix-class has example of that proxy class.

Comment: @Jarod42 I had a really good one somewhere but couldn't find it :( Recreated a pauper's version instead

Comment: Pretty sure there are dup also, but cannot find it, `[]` might be interpreted as empty tag in search :-/

Comment: @Jarod42 Didn't even bother trying to use symbol search ^_^ I've just used so many variations on the theme of "matrix" "2d vector" "two-dimensional vectors" "facade" "indexes" "indices" "proxy class" "helper type" blah blah over the years that I can't find my gem :(

Comment: @Jarod42 Ah, [it was on a deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52278399/error-no-match-operator-when-overloading-operator-in-matrix-structure-c#comment91505570_52278399) #sadface Anyway it looks pretty much the same as this one :D

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit things get deleted too easily around here.

Comment: @MarkRansom Yes indeed!