# how to turn a vector into a matrix C++ vec2mat

Tags: c++

i've recently seen this code which i believe to be the equivelant to vec2mat from matlab to C++ :

```
int mat vec2mat(vec V, size_t cols) {
size_t rows = std::ceil(V.n_elems / double(cols));
return V.reshape(cols, rows);// return the original vector as matrix
```

And i've tried to apply that to my code, but without success. I hope someone can help me find the right way to do so. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
int main() 
{
    int cargas[20];
    srand(time(NULL));
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) 
    {
        cargas[i] = (rand() % 5) + 1;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        printf("%d ", cargas[i]);
}
```

(i would like to turn the vector into a 4x5 matrix)

Comment: How have you tried to apply that your code? (Which looks like C, not C++, and would benefit a lot from consistent indentation and use of braces)

Comment: [Maybe like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53952344/560648)?

Comment: I did try.. please help..

Answer (score 1):

The routine you have posted appears to be using the [armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/) library. A corrected version could be:

```
#include <armadillo>

arma::mat vec2mat(const arma::vec& V, size_t cols)
{
  size_t rows = std::ceil(V.n_elem / double(cols));
  return arma::reshape(V, rows, cols);
}
```

Notice that the routine requires a `armadillo` type `arma::vec` as an input; it does not work with a C-style array, but you could, say, convert it into a `arma::vec`.

Please see the [armadillo documentation](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html) for more information on the library.